# How to deleteMany in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, apollo

I have a database like this:

```js
User {
 id: 12323,
 name: asdasd,
 products: [{ id: 1, name: asdasdl }, {id: 2, name: bfcvc}]
}
```

With `deleteMany`, I want to remove all that have products name `'asdasdl'`.

How can I do this?

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```js
await User.deleteMany({'name': { '$in': User.products }}, {});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$eq operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#mongodb-query-op.-eq) like this

```js
await User.deleteMany({ 'products.name': { $e: 'asdasdl' }});
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the query parameter, you can get all documents with a products.name == 'asdasdl' and then delete them:

```js
await User.deleteMany({ 'products' : { 'name': 'asdasdl' }});
```

See [deleteMany docs here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany) and
[Mongo queries on arrays here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)